# ¿como agregar un request Headers con $http de angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy haciendo un consumo de servicio y quiero agregar un header al metodo get de la siguiente forma.

```
    var header={headers: {'idUser': Constants.appConfig.userParam} };
    return {
        obtenerInformacionUsuario: () => 
           $http.get(${BASE_URL2}/obtenerInformacionUsuario, header)
    }
```

En `Constants.appConfig.userParam`se guarda una cadena, el servicio si retorna datos y todo pero el problema esta en que no me agrega el idUser al Request Headers.

Comment: a tu objeto header, le falta la key headers. Sería asi: `var header = {headers:{'idUser': Constants.appConfig.userParam}}`

Comment: @Naimad ya lo he intentado así y no funciona...

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando el metodo `$http` directamente especificandole los headers:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '${BASE_URL2}/obtenerInformacionUsuario',
    data: 'data=1',
    headers: {
         "idUser": Constants.appConfig.userParam
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    //...
});
```